# Is it possible to query/browse the JNDI tree in WebSphere Liberty?

Tags: java, ejb, jndi, websphere-liberty

I have a EJB with a remote interface that I want to access from a client. I have difficulties to build the string for the JNDI lookup. Is there a command line tool which shows all register enterprise beans in the naming service? Or can I see this in a log file?

The JNDI name should look like this:

corbaname:localhost:2809#ejb/global/MyApp/MyModule/EJBName!full.package.remote.interface.Name

I’m also not really sure if my app and module name in the string is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to dump the JNDI namespace on WebSphere Liberty ([there is a way to do this in WebSphere traditional](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tnam_dump_utility.html)).

The easiest way to check what JNDI name your EJBs are registered at, is to check the messages.log file.  In the messages.log file you should see some `CNTR0167I` messages which indicate where the server has bound your EJBs. The messages.log file can be found in `${server.config.dir}/logs/messages.log`.

Example EJB binding message:

> CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.example.DatabaseBean interface of the DatabaseBean enterprise bean in the TestProject.war module of the TestProject application.  The binding location is: **java:global/TestProject/DatabaseBean!com.example.DatabaseBean**

For more info, check out the IBM doc:
[Using enterprise JavaBeans with remote interfaces on Liberty](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_ejb_remote.html)